# How to handle hundreds of pagination in AngularJS + Laravel4?

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, coffeescript, pagination

I have a case where I have to pull data from the server and make pagination in the results. There are thousands of the data, and I'm planning to show 20 items per page.

My plan is to call this Laravel function each time new page is clicked:

```
public static function GetPagingListing($limLow=null, $limTop=null) {
    $data = array();
    $results = DB::table('news')->orderBy('date','desc')->limit($limLow, $limTop)->get(array('id','title','category','edituser','date'));

    if($results != null) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach($results as $k=>$v) {
            $data[$i][] = $v;
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $count = DB::table('news')->count(); //this gives total count of the data, for pagination later

    return Response::json(['data'=>$data, 'count'=> ($count/20)]);
}
```

Then my current way of displaying the pagination is this (.html in Angular):

```
<ul>
                <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
                    <a href ng-click="prevPage()"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>&nbsp;Before</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-repeat="n in range(itemCount)" ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}" ng-click="setPage()">
                    <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == newsList.length - 1}">
                    <a href ng-click="nextPage()">After&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

This all works fine, but the total of my data count is 1000+, that's like 50+ pagination that user can click. How to make the pagination like `[<prev][1][2][3][...][21][22][23][...][50][51][52][next>]` (or at least a logic)?

**EDIT**

Solved my problem using Angular UI Bootstrap:

`<pagination total-items="itemCount" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" max-size="5"></pagination>`

with its cdn:

`<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.bootstrap/0.7.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Why is this tagged "coffeescript"?

Comment: because the angular js I write using `coffeescript`, but I didn't post my angular code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just think about this recently, and my conclusion is that the logic of the pagination is surprisingly involved. One place you can look for inspiration is Wordpress's `paginate_links` function http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1988.

You need to know the total number of pages `total`, the current page `current`, number of first/last pages to be displayed `end_size` (3 in your example) and the number of pages around the current page `mid_size` (1 in your example); then:

- if total < 2, no pagination needed
- if current > 1, shows prev
- for n from 1 to total:

  - if n <= end_size (the first part) or n > total - end_size (the last part) or (n >= current - mid_size and n <= current + mid_size) (the middle part), display link to page n
  - else display dots if not displayed
- if current < total, shows next

Comment: thanks for your answer, you logic gives me inspiration on the mid paging, I solved my problem with angular bootstrap though